# Communication between CLIPS (expert system) and C - CLIPS and MATLAB

Tags: c, matlab, expert-system, clips

I have a `C` function called `"amortiss.c"` and I want to connect it to `CLIPS (Expert System Tool)`. Infact, I want to pass the variable "`result`" returned by the function `"amortiss.c"` to `CLIPS` so that it compares this "`result`" to 1 and then displays messages depending on the comparaison

```
if (result <1) then (do...); 
else if (result ==1) then do (...);
```

According to the `Clips` user guide I should define an external function called user-defined function. The problem is that this function is a CLIPS function written in `C` ..so I don't see how it helps me connect my "`amortiss.c`" to `CLIPS`.

Is it also possible to connect Clips to `Matlab`? (communication between .clp file and .m file)?

I appreciate all your suggestions and advice.

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me communicate at least between Clips and .CSV file ?? In fact I want my C function amortiss.c passes the result to a .CSV File and then Clips uses this result to do some calculation via a C function (called in Clips: user defined function) . I need your help. So pleas help me !!! I appreciate all your suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define an external function. That would be if you wanted CLIPS to call a C function.

Check out section "4.4.4 CreateFact" in this document:

http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/documentation/v624/apg.htm

It shows how to assert new facts into the CLIPS environment. The previous section 4.4.3 gives an example how to assert a new string into CLIPS. I have not tested the string assert, but I can confirm the 4.4.4 example works with a deftemplate.

For example, create a text file, "foo.clp":

```
(deftemplate foo
 (slot x (type INTEGER) )
 (slot y (type INTEGER) )
)

(defrule IsOne
?f<-(foo (x ?xval))
(test (= ?xval 1))
=>
(printout t ?xval " is equal to 1" crlf)
)

(defrule NotOne
?f<-(foo (x ?xval))
(test (!= ?xval 1))
=>
(printout t ?xval " is not equal to 1" crlf)
)
```

And create a C program "foo.c"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "clips.h"

int addFact(int result)
{

  VOID *newFact;
  VOID *templatePtr;
  DATA_OBJECT theValue;

  //==================
  // Create the fact. 
  //==================
  templatePtr = FindDeftemplate("foo");
  newFact = CreateFact(templatePtr);

  if (newFact == NULL) return -1;

  //======================================
  // Set the value of the x
  //======================================
  theValue.type = INTEGER;
  theValue.value = AddLong(result);
  PutFactSlot(newFact,"x",&theValue);

  int rval;

  if (Assert(newFact) != NULL){
    Run(-1);
    rval = 0;
  }
  else{
    rval = -2;
  }

  return rval;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

  if (argc < 2) {
    printf("Usage: ");
    printf(argv[0]);
    printf(" <Clips File>\n");
    return 0;
  }
  else {

    InitializeEnvironment();
    Reset();

    char *waveRules = argv[1];     
    int wv = Load(waveRules);

    if(wv != 1){
      printf("Error opening wave rules!\n");
    }

    int result = 1;

    addFact(result);
    result = 3;
    addFact(result);
  }
  return 0;

}
```

Run with:

```
foo foo.clp
```

It might be overkill, but I think it gets the job done!